# AsyncTask setMessage after some time android java

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

hi i have AsyncTask in my app but i am unable to change its setMessage

for example :-

```
private class ProgressTask1 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

        public ProgressTask1(MainActivity mainActivity) {
        context = mainActivity;
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    }

    private Context context;

    protected void onPreExecute() {

        this.dialog.setMessage("Checking system...");
        this.dialog.setCancelable(false);
        this.dialog.setTitle("Please Wait...");
        this.dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        this.dialog.show();
    }
```

now i want that setmessage to change i tried adding it in doinbackground

```
    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {

    dothis1();
    this.dialog.setMessage("one done...");

dothis2();
this.dialog.setMessage("two done...");
```

but this is making app force close and do not rate it low because i tried my best and searched forum but could able to fix this so asked for hand at this nice community :)

anybody can help ? :)

ERROR

> 05-13 23:36:34.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2454): Caused by:
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the
>   original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Comment: If you solved it, post your solution!

Comment: no problem exist i dont know whats the real problem

Comment: see @alenz316 answer, you must use the other methods in the async to do this. Personally, I like to do one final update in `onPostExecute`, this is after ALL work has finished.

Comment: yes that cool but somehow its good to give user idea where is progress right now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ohmm, you should not update UI from background thread. To update UI, you can do by two ways:

1) Using `publishProgress (Progress... values)` and `onProgressUpdate(...)`. To do that, you must change your `AsynTask` class:

```
 private class ProgressTask1 extends AsyncTask<String, String, Boolean> {

    //.......... //your init
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        //your background handle

        //publish to change UI
        String toShow = "your_string_here";
        publishProgress(toShow);
        //return ...; //your return value
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        //detect message and show it.
        //this.dialog.setMessage(values[0]);
    }
}
```

2) Using `onPostExecute(....)`:

```
private class ProgressTask1 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    //.......... //your init

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        //your background handle
        //return ...;//your return value
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        String toShow = "your_string_here";
        //this.dialog.setMessage(toShow);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You cannot update the UI from the background.**

See [AsyncTask.onProgressUpdate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate(Progress...)) to update the UI based on your background progress. :D

Comment: Yes or with `onPostExecute` :)

Comment: i somehow did not get can you do me favor by writing bit of code

Comment: Don't really have time to write it for you. But use `publishProgress (Progress... values)` in `doInBackground()` which will call `onProgressUpdate()` on the UI thread.

Comment: thats i tried but not working for me im sure im doing wrong :(